# Why did `cherry-pick begin..end` return conflicts when `rebase --onto` didn't?

Tags: git

I recently hit unexpected conflicts when running a `git cherry-pick`:

```
git checkout myBranch
git cherry-pick begin..end
```

I thought "that makes no sense", aborted, and tried what I understand to be the equivalent `git rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto myBranch begin end
```

Voilà! A clean rebase, no unexpected conflicts.

Am I right to be surprised? Do you think there was user error somewhere, or is there a fundamental difference in the processes underlying `rebase --onto` and `cherry-pick` that could result in this?

**Edit**: In the `cherry-pick`, `begin` and `end` were SHAs. In the `rebase`, `begin` was that same SHA used for the `cherry-pick`'s `begin`,  and `end` was the name of a branch the tip of which was at the `cherry-pick`'s `end` commit.

Comment: Was the end result correct? Did you get the right commits where you wanted them?

Comment: Yes. And I'm afraid I didn't dig into the details of cherry-pick's conflicts, so this is "in theory..." for now

Comment: This being git, nothing is ever lost (unless you go out of your way to lose it); so you could reproduce the cherry-pick operation.  e.g. `git branch myBranch_old myBranch@{1}` and then run the cherry-pick onto `myBranch_old` to see what was going on.  Some additional insight about the nature of the conflicts, and/or more info about the commit topology in the range `begin..end`, might really shed some light here

Comment: To find the answer you should check the conflicting commit and compare it with the one in rebase case. Was it skipped as in the answer below? Was it applied succesfully? In the latter case, was result before the commit same for cherrypick and rebase?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger  that's the "for now" - hope to play with that in a few days and come back with an update. Figured I'd start with throwing out the basic question in case there was a clear answer.

Comment: @max630 yep it applied successfully

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR one line summary: `git rebase` omits any already-cherry-picked commits.

---

What `git rebase` copies is not quite what you think.  (I admit I am guessing a bit about what you think here ... but if the result was a surprise, this must be true.)

Formally, the arguments are, according to [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), `[--onto newbase] upstream [branch]`.  That is:

> ```
> git rebase --onto myBranch begin end
> ```

means that `end` is treated as a branch name:

```
git checkout end
```

After that, according to the documentation (*but it lies*), the commits to be cherry-picked are those produced by `git rev-list` or `git log` when given `upstream..HEAD`:

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in <upstream> are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of commits that would be shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`; or by `git log 'fork_point'..HEAD`, if `--fork-point` is active (see the description on `--fork-point` below); or by `git log HEAD`, if the `--root` option is specified.

Neither of the `--fork-point` or `--root` options applies, so we are left with:

```
git log begin..HEAD
```

Since `HEAD` now refers to `end`, this *would be* the same as `begin..end`.  However, as I just noted, the documentation lies!  Well, at least a little bit.  It then corrects things to say:

> Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted ...

It should also mention here that `git rebase` omits merge commits as well.  What we actually need is more complicated:

```
git rev-list --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges begin...HEAD
```

(note three dots instead of two).  That is, we examine `begin..HEAD`, to find commits to possibly take (`--right-only`); but then we look through `HEAD..begin` (the three dots in `begin...HEAD`) for commits that we could take, but decide not to, as they are already taken (`--cherry-pick`).  From the resulting list of commits, we also throw out any merge commits<sup>1</sup> (`--no-merges`).

Given that the two two-dot *`X..Y`* formulations (`begin..HEAD` and `begin..end`) *would* produce the same list, and the point at which we would begin copying commits (`newBranch`) is also the same, it follows that any change in behavior *must* be due to the omitting step.  If you were to check out the original tip commit of `myBranch` and run:

```
git rev-list ... | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

(where `...` uses the `--cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges` three-dot formulation and specifies the commits that `begin` and `end` *used to* identify before all these changes), it should also just work, the same way the `git rebase` did.

---

<sup>1</sup>Merge commits are not the problem here.  To cherry-pick a merge, `git cherry-pick` *requires* that you supply a `-m` parameter.  But if there are any non-merge commits, `git cherry-pick` *forbids* a `-m` parameter.  Since there were clearly some non-merges and no complaint regarding `-m`, we did not hit a merge commit.

Comment: Will have to investigate further to see if this is what happened to me, but no matter what this is awesome. Your "means that end is treated as a branch name" made me realize my question as originally worded was misleading: in the `rebase` command, the `[branch]` _was_ a branch name (see the edit I added)

Comment: Note the key phrase is "same textual changes" - which certainly will include any cherry-picked commit, but could also include, say, a small fix-up commit that was made independently on both sides. (In fact, the reason I always forget about this behavior is that it's always described as "skips cherry-picked commits", and that never makes sense to me because git shouldn't *really* know if a commit was cherry-picked; so it just never sticks in my head.)  If such a commit exists - regardless of how it got there - it would definitely cause cherry-pick to conflict which is why rebase skips it...